# How can the [UsedImplicitly] attribute be used on a namespace level?

Tags: resharper, code-analysis

ReSharper has a [UsedImplicitly] attribute which ignores properties that are not being directly referenced. This is recommended to be used by JetBrains: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/MemberCanBePrivate.Global.html

Is there any way to apply this attribute at a namespace level? Or is there another way to ignore all classes within a given namespace (and possibly all child namespaces)?

Answer (score 10):

This answer does not answer the question but it might be helpful.

I have an attribute called `PluginEntryPointAttribute`.

```cs
public class PluginEntryPointAttribute : Attribute 
{
}
```

And my code used to look like this:

```cs
[PluginEntryPointAttribute]
[UsedImplicitly]
public void SomeEntryMethod()
{
    // code
}
```

I need the UsedImplicitly attribute so that ReSharper does not mark my SomeEntryMethod as not used.

---

My new code looks like this thanks to `[JetBrains.Annotations.MeansImplicitUse]`:

```cs
[JetBrains.Annotations.MeansImplicitUse]
public class PluginEntryPointAttribute : Attribute 
{
}
```

Now on my code, I do not need to include the UsedImplicitly attribute:

```cs
[PluginEntryPointAttribute]
// [UsedImplicitly] no need to use it because PluginEntryPointAttribute has the MeansImplicitUse attribute
public void SomeEntryMethod()
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, I've been looking for this quite a while!